# Как работать с многомерным массивом приходящим в ответ на AJAX запрос?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Пожалуйста помогите!
В ответ на AJAX запрос приходит JSON такого вида:

```
{
    "doctors": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Сергеев Иван Петрович",
            "primary_spec": "Хирург",
            "primary_spec_id": "34",
            "specs": [
                {
                    "id": "32",
                    "name": "Аллерголог"
                },
                {
                    "id": "34",
                    "name": "Хирург"
                }
            ],
            "schedules": [
                {
                    "id": "2005",
                    "build_id": "1",
                    "build_name": "Корпус 1",
                    "room": "Кабинет № 2",
                    "address": "ул. Космонавтов, 41",
                    "kind": "0",
                    "date": "18.08.2020",
                    "start": "08:00",
                    "end": "09:00",
                    "intervals": [
                        {
                            "start": "08:00",
                            "end": "08:20",
                            "free": true
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "08:20",
                            "end": "08:40",
                            "free": true
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "08:40",
                            "end": "09:00",
                            "free": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Не могу понять как пройти циклом и вывести "intervals"[{start}] к примеру списком, если "intervals"[{"free": true}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перебирая по очереди каждый вложенный список

```js
const data = {
    "doctors": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Сергеев Иван Петрович",
            "primary_spec": "Хирург",
            "primary_spec_id": "34",
            "specs": [
                {
                    "id": "32",
                    "name": "Аллерголог"
                },
                {
                    "id": "34",
                    "name": "Хирург"
                }
            ],
            "schedules": [
                {
                    "id": "2005",
                    "build_id": "1",
                    "build_name": "Корпус 1",
                    "room": "Кабинет № 2",
                    "address": "ул. Космонавтов, 41",
                    "kind": "0",
                    "date": "18.08.2020",
                    "start": "08:00",
                    "end": "09:00",
                    "intervals": [
                        {
                            "start": "08:00",
                            "end": "08:20",
                            "free": true
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "08:20",
                            "end": "08:40",
                            "free": true
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "08:40",
                            "end": "09:00",
                            "free": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


const schedules = data["doctors"]["schedules"];

for (let k = 0; k < data["doctors"].length; k++) 
  for (let i = 0; i < data["doctors"][k]["schedules"].length; i++)
    for (let j = 0; j < data["doctors"][k]["schedules"][i]["intervals"].length; j++) {
      const interval = data["doctors"][k]["schedules"][i]["intervals"][j];
      if(interval.free) console.log(interval);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Ну или в в функциональном стиле.

```js
const data = {
    "doctors": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Сергеев Иван Петрович",
            "primary_spec": "Хирург",
            "primary_spec_id": "34",
            "specs": [
                {
                    "id": "32",
                    "name": "Аллерголог"
                },
                {
                    "id": "34",
                    "name": "Хирург"
                }
            ],
            "schedules": [
                {
                    "id": "2005",
                    "build_id": "1",
                    "build_name": "Корпус 1",
                    "room": "Кабинет № 2",
                    "address": "ул. Космонавтов, 41",
                    "kind": "0",
                    "date": "18.08.2020",
                    "start": "08:00",
                    "end": "09:00",
                    "intervals": [
                        {
                            "start": "08:00",
                            "end": "08:20",
                            "free": true
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "08:20",
                            "end": "08:40",
                            "free": true
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "08:40",
                            "end": "09:00",
                            "free": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


const doctors = data.doctors;

doctors.forEach(doctor => doctor.schedules.forEach(schedule => schedule.intervals.forEach(interval => {if (interval.free) console.log(interval)})))
```

Comment: Этот вариант тоже рабочий, спасибо!